# How to Change Google Map Mode

Tags: android, google-maps

It seems quite easy but I tried many things, and havent solved yet.

I use a webview to show map. here is the url

```
String url = "https://maps.google.com/?saddr="+UPlat+","+UPlng+"&daddr="+lat+","+lng;
```

and it show turn by turn mode on webview like the first image, but if I can click a button that is left side of "Direction" on the map, It turns map like the second image:

[image] [image]

I want to use that map when I open url. I mean,it starts with turn by turn mode, but I want to change it as map view mode.

I know that I must add some parameters. But It doesnt work. I added these

&zoom=14
&views=traffic
&mapmode=streetview

but result is the same.. I dont want to use google map api for it. Because I already use place API, and i want to solve it with url.